# Is there any cross platform file IO / path util library for C?

Tags: c, file-io, path, cross-platform

Is there some C library that implements platform independent version of path operations?

Some examples that come to mind:

- Getting the absolute path from a relative one (without requiring the file to exist)
- Ensuring a directory exists.
- Creating a file if non-existent, and any directory in the given path that is missing.
- Concatenating paths.
- Getting directory part of path.
- Getting filename part of path.
- Lots more....

There are of course platform specific versions of these, but they hardly ever do exactly the same thing leading to chaos trying to match behaviour across platforms.

And I mean C, not C++, so boost doesn't count.

Also if there is none, are there any good sources/examples of differences between platforms, and other useful information that can be used to write such a library?

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a standard one. Coming from java which has `Paths.get("/path/to/myfile.txt")`, I'm disappointed.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a rather old question, but I have been looking for something like this and couldn't find anything. So I wrote one, [cwalk](https://github.com/likle/cwalk) ([reference](https://likle.github.io/cwalk/reference/)) - for anyone who still finds it useful! :-)

Comment: Very cool! This is the kind of response I like to see.

Answer (score 3):

The ever-nice [glib family (part of GTK+)](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) has some, at least.

- The [misc utility functions API](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html) has functions like [`g_path_is_absolute()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-path-is-absolute) and others
- The I/O virtualization wrapper API GIO has [`g_file_make_directory_with_parents()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-make-directory-with-parents).

Note that some of the functions you're describing, such as "getting absolute path from relative one" assumes the existence of a current directory, which is how that resolution is typically done. It's not a very "pure" function, since it relies on external state. In Windows, with its "split file system", there is even one current directory per volume (e.g. one for C:\, one for A:\ if you have it, and so on) per process.

Comment: Thanks. `g_path_get_basename`, `g_path_get_dirname` are the kind of ones I want too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the [Apache Portable Runtime Project (APR)](http://apr.apache.org/) which does a lot more than just file I/O and path operations. And is not tied to any project like Gnome.

Another project that has portable functions for this with a nice API is [CZMQ](http://czmq.zeromq.org/) with the [zfile](http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual:zfile) and [zsys](http://czmq.zeromq.org/manual:zsys) classes, although the library itself focuses on other things.