# How to compare two (absolute) paths (given as char* ) in C and check if they are the same?

Tags: c

Given two paths as char*, I can't determine if the two paths are pointing to the same file.
How to implement in C a platform-independent utility to check if paths are pointing to the same file or not.

Using strcmp will not work because on windows paths can contain \ or /
Using ist_ino will not help because it does not work on windows

```
    char *fileName = du->getFileName();
    char *oldFileName = m_duPtr->getFileName();
    bool isSameFile = pathCompare(fileName, oldFileName) == 0;//(strcmp(fileName, oldFileName) == 0);
    if (isSameFile){
        stat(fileName, &pBuf);
        stat(oldFileName, &pBuf2);

        if (pBuf.st_ino == pBuf2.st_ino){
            bRet = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you can use external libraries there are some suggestions in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355904/is-there-any-cross-platform-file-io-path-util-library-for-c?rq=1

Comment: The \ and / is not as much as an issue as the C:, D: etc issue.

Comment: @bdegnan you probably mean that windows allows to mount drives anywhere, so comparing strings doesn't work (not even mentionning junctions...)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Indeed.  I'm primarily a *unix user, and I wrote strcmp that ignored everything after ":".  It worked great until someone decided to put it on "d:".  I guess you could treat it as a subpath and make the c: d: just a windows check.

Comment: @jpw I can't use any external library.

Comment: One of the method is to use stack. Go folder by folder and push them to stack. Pop when you encounter ../ or ..\. Do it for both the paths and then compare if stacks are identical.

Comment: This will be difficult when it comes to relative paths, networks drives, unicode, special folders (e.g. %AppData%) etc. There won't be a general solution that works on all platforms for all cases. You either have to limit yourself to very specific cases or use conditional compilation and provide algorithms for each supported platform.

Comment: If the path will always be an absolute path and there will be no relative paths. How can I do so?

Comment: @AmrRady if you create the path name in the exact same way and hard links are ignored (which could point to the same file but have a different path) then you can simply use strcmp

Comment: @gtzkw what you mean is that the problem will be limited to handling  // and \ separators only?

Comment: @AmrRady that's what I meant with "create the path name in the exact same way". Just make sure to use only slashes or backslashes. Don't mix them. If you don't have control over the path creation you're screwed because then you can't ensure that non of the special cases occur.

Comment: Note that most Unix systems have case-sensitive file systems; macOS (by default) and Windows have case-insensitive file systems (so `abc` and `ABC` refer to the same file).  On a Unix system, a backslash can appear within a file name (not as a directory separator).  You can't write the code in a wholly platform-independent manner.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Hard links also exist on Windows and the C standard library has no methods for operating on them.

Plausible solutions to the larger problem: link against cygwin1.dll and use the st_ino method. You omitted st_dev from your sample code and need to put it back.

While there is an actual way to accomplish this on Windows, it involves ntdll methods and I had to read Cygwin's code to find out how to do it.

The methods are NtGetFileInformationByHandle and NtFsGetVolumeInformationNyHandle. There are documented kernel32 calls that claim to do the same thing. See the cygwin source code for why they don't work right (buggy fs drivers).